# Calculate 2 (define a function for 2 where the model is a line)

Tags: r, linear-regression, least-squares, chi-squared

I have to calculate chi-square for given data , which contain three variable:  years,fraction lost and error.  I have used this formula
 [image]

where y = fraction lost , x = years and sigma is the error. a and b constants.

```
fun.to.minimize <- function(params,x,y,z) {
    p1 <- params[1]
    p2 <- params[2]
    output <- sum(((y- p1- x*p2)/z)^2)
    return(output)
}

p1  =  20
p2  =100
solution <- optim(c(p1,p2), fun.to.minimize, x=frac$YEAR, y=frac$FRACLOST, z=frac$ERROR)
new.p1 <- solution$par[1]
print(solution)
```

And the output is:

```
$par
[1] 38.52325439 -0.01525879

$value
[1] 607820.8

$counts
function gradient 
      41       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Did I implement the formula correctly and is there any R built-in function to cross-check the values for confirmation.

Comment: Have a look at lm function.